# Automatically let git open custom merge tool for certain extensions

Tags: git, git-merge, mergetool

I've written a small custom diff/merge tool to visually merge PowerPoint files. It launches PowerPoint in Compare/Merge mode.

I'm trying to register it as the default tool git should use when diffing and merging any powerpoint files.

I added the following to the `.gitconfig`:

```
[difftool "pptdiffmerge"]
    name = PowerPoint Diff tool
    cmd = C:/ppt-diffmerge-tool/bin/Debug/ppt-diffmerge-tool.exe "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
    binary = true
[mergetool "pptdiffmerge"]
    name = PowerPoint Merge tool
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
    cmd = C:/ppt-diffmerge-tool/bin/Debug/ppt-diffmerge-tool.exe "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$RESULT"
```

And this to the `.gitattributes`:

```
*.ppt   binary diff=pptdiffmerge merge=pptdiffmerge
*.pptm  binary diff=pptdiffmerge merge=pptdiffmerge
*.pptx  binary diff=pptdiffmerge merge=pptdiffmerge
```

And when I run  `git difftool --tool-help` my custom tool is listed:

```
C:\Users\jesse\source\repos\ppt-diffmerge> git difftool --tool-help
'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
                vimdiff
                vimdiff1
                vimdiff2
                vimdiff3

        user-defined:
                pptdiffmerge.cmd C:/ppt-diffmerge-tool/bin/Debug/ppt-diffmerge-tool.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE
                pptdiffmerge.cmd C:/ppt-diffmerge-tool/bin/Debug/ppt-diffmerge-tool.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $RESULT
```

So far so good...

But when I run `git difftool sample.pptx`, it doesn't suggest to use mine. When I call `git difftool sample.pptx -tpptdiffmerge`, then it does work.

What am I missing here...

Comment: `binary` is a "macro attribute" that means `-diff -merge -text`. Presumably `binary diff=... merge=...` overrides the `-diff` and `-merge` parts but just for clarity I'd write `-text diff=... merge=...` rather than using the macro. The lack of suggestion is probably not due to this, though, it's probably just a bug in `git difftool`.

Comment: No dice. Still asking to launch the default diff tool... :(.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably want to go in to the `git difftool` code and make it smarter and send in an enhancement. I personally have the opinion that the whole difftool/mergetool setup in Git needs a complete overhaul, but I'm not about to do it myself. :-)